# Primitive element (fields)

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

I'm re-reading the primitive element lemma and I can't reason the following concept. Let $f,g\in F[x]$ be in the polynomial ring of one variable over the field $F$. Let those two polynomials have a unique common simple root $\beta$. Then the largest unary common divisor of $f$ and $g$, with coefficients in $F$ is $x-\beta$.

How come $x-\beta\in F[x]$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Euclid's algorithm for calculating the gcd of $f$ and $g$ will never leave the ring $F[x]$. Because $F$ is a field you can normalize the result to be monic (=leading coefficient equal to one) in the end.

Comment: And if $E$ is an extension field, Euclid's algorithm will run with exactly the same steps in both $F[x]$ and $E[x]$.

Comment: Well, I guess my question now turns into why Euclid's algorithm runs with the same steps in both $F[x]$ and $E[x]$.

Comment: If $a(x),b(x)\in K[x]$ where $K$ is any field, then you can prove that there exist **unique** polynomials $q(x),r(x)\in K[x]$ such that
$$a(x)=q(x)b(x)+r(x)$$ and $\deg r<\deg b$. Such $q,r$ exist in $F[x]$ and by the uniqueness part of the result the solutions are the same in $E[x]$.